# WebdriverIO: How to run file-uploading AutoIt .exe script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit, webdriver-io

I am using [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/) to run a file-uploading `.exe` created with [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

I am running the script inside a `browser.execute` command. The file needs to run from the local drive and execute wd in Chrome browser.
Here is the code :

```
this.open("https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf");
this.SubmitClick("//div[@class='l0v3m7-3 hIetmU']");
this.BrowserSleep(2000);
scr.runAutoItScript('C:\\test\\desktopApp\\autoit', 'fileUpload.exe')


//scr have the child process:
const { execFile } = require('child_process').execFile;
module.exports = {
  runAutoItScript(pathToScript, scriptName) {
    console.info(`\n> Started execution of ${pathToScript} / ${scriptName} ...`);

    execFile(`${pathToScript}/${scriptName}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else {
        console.info(`\n> Finished execution of ${scriptName}! | Output: ${stdout}`);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember doing something like this in the past and I used NodeJS's [child_process.execFile](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) command. The documentation is heavy on **child_process**, so read carefully.

You should end up with something along the lines of:

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

let runAutoItScript = function(pathToScript, scriptName) {
  console.info(`\n> Started execution of ${scriptName} ...`);

  execFile(`${pathToScript}/${scriptName}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      // > do something with the script output <
      console.info(`\n> Finished execution of ${scriptName}! | Output: ${stdout}`);
    }
  });
}

runAutoItScript('/this/is/a/valid/path', 'AwesomeScript.exe');
```

Next step would be to minify it and make it run inside `browser.execute` call.

You can find a lot of **child_process** examples online, just leverage the resources available to run the simplest script. Develop from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit. I get : TypeError: execFile is not a function; both with browser.execute and without using it - directly calling node function given above.
-------------
code: 
    this.open("https://smallpdf.com/word-to-pdf");
    this.SubmitClick("//div[@class='l0v3m7-3 hIetmU']");
    this.BrowserSleep(1111);
    scr.runAutoItScript('C:\\test\\desktopApp\\autoit', 'fileUpload.exe')

Comment: @tanjs, can you update the question with the code snippet (_format it accordingly_) instead of using the comment section? Try to give some context for what you are trying to achieve, as an end-to-end flow.

Comment: I want to complete the file uploading when the web page has a drop file functionality (type='file' tag not present) - with selenium file selection diaglog box opened. The next step to give the file path and click ok button achieved with autoit script. stuck at the second step.

Comment: Thanks @Dan its resolved with: {} removal     -------          
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

Comment: Strange, thought there was a named export for `execFile`, also the documentation suggested the same. Seems `child_process` logic uses a default export.

Comment: Also browser.execute was not required - direct node function was called in code flow.